# How to download private Soundcloud track with access token in bash script

Tags: python, bash, api, download, soundcloud

I have generated a list of Soundcloud track id's with the following python code:

```
import soundcloud
import urllib

client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                       client_secret='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                       username='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                       password='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

f=open('soundcloud-track-ids', 'w+')

count = 0
while count < 6000:
    tracks = client.get('/me/tracks', limit=200, offset=count)
    for track in tracks:
        print >>f, track.id, "\t", track.title .encode('utf-8')
    count += 200

f.close()
```

I have then run a bash script to backup the entire archive to contents to a hard drive:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

while read line; do
    if [ ! -f /mnt/drobo_1/Soundcloud/$(echo $line | cut -f 2- | sed 's,/,\ ,g').mp3 ];     then
        wget https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/"$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')"/download?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX \
        -O /mnt/drobo_1/Soundcloud/"$(echo $line | cut -f 2- | sed 's,/,\ ,g').mp3"
    fi
done < ./soundcloud-track-ids

IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Nearly all of the 5317 tracks are private, and most have downloaded without a problem, however about 600 tracks have failed to download with the following error:

```
--2015-01-05 12:46:09--  https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/152288957/download?oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Resolving api.soundcloud.com (api.soundcloud.com)... 93.184.220.127
Connecting to api.soundcloud.com (api.soundcloud.com)|93.184.220.127|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-01-05 12:46:10 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Does anyone know what the error could be?

Comment: Who downvoted this question, there is literally nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

That 404 error is saying the file couldn't be found at SoundCloud's end. It could be SoundCloud's rate limiter doing this, preventing you from hammering it so much.

See https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#quotas

If you try those failed downloads later, do they work?